# How to have C# open a website and run javascript on it

Tags: javascript, c#, web

I am trying to make a program that automatically buys items for me I have gotten everything to work, but I am trying to make it so when you click a button it runs java script on a website ex. google.com (basically making it automatic instead of having to do f12 go to console then hit enter).

I have been able to get it to work when I do F12

Not too much to show im stumped on where to start.

I want to make it so (in my C# program) it automatically runs java script on a website when you click a button.

Comment: Have you think about chrome extensions? It can do what you ask for.

Comment: No I made a program in visual studio for it, it is using C#.

Comment: You can take a look at the [CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) library, it is a chrome browser inside your wpf/winforms app where you can [call javascript, have callbacks, and expose .NET classes](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#javascript-integration). There is also mshtml with the .net framework WebBrowser but that's a horrible api.

Answer (score 0):

I see several ways:

1. Chrome extension that allows to make what you asked for. Sure it works only if you browser is open.
2. The other way is to explore whether the target site accept ajax requests and allows to perform buying operations. Something like a simple api. So you can call this from your C# program.

To test if they has API you can look at a network requests in chrome dev tools and find ajax requests for needed operations, something like `/buy?product_id=231` or `products?page=3`. Then try to fetch that urls and get a correct response. It means you can send such requests from your C# program.

There could be some pitfalls like required cookies or headers, but it is just a matter of time to find this out.

Comment: I already have the bot made, you put the script in a IOS shortcut and run it on a website. I want to make it so that when you are in my application you can click "start" and then a web-browser will open and it will run java script on it.

Comment: So, let's make it clear. Are you trying to implement this on iOS and use it only on iPhone or iPad? And does your js script written already?

Comment: Well right now im using it for computer you then move over the JS to your phone but I would like to make this work for IOS, How would I make JS auto run on ios through a APP?

Comment: I don't think this is the right way to implement what you want. Try to think the other way and maybe to call api from C# is preferable?